# jQuery validate and AJAX post with save button out of form [Solved]

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to validate the form inputs should be filled as required and after the data to be posted into the database. I saw an example in stackoverflow, did not save the link unfortunately, where someone posted that this code is possible...

Edit - I will provide the code here since I've succeeded to solve this with the help of @epascarello. It would be great to see any alternatives to solving this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#apiform").validate({
    rules: {
      sku: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 9,
      },
      name: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 20,
      },
      price: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 5,
      },
      productType: {
        required: true,
      },
      size: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 4,
      },
      weight: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 4,
      },
      height: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 3,
      },
      width: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 3,
      },
      length: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 3,
      }
      },
      messages: {
        sku: {
          required: "Please, enter valid SKU",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 9 characters"
        },
        name: {
          required: "Please, enter valid name",
          maxlength: "Please enter "
        },
        price: {
          required: "Please, enter price",
          maxlength: ""
        },
        productType: {
          required: "Please select an option from the list",
        },
        size: {
          required: "Please, provide the size of the DVD",
          maxlength: ""
        },
        weight: {
          required: "Please, provide the weight",
          maxlength: ""
        },
        height: {
          required: "Please, provide the required dimension",
          maxlength: ""
        },
        width: {
          required: "Please, provide the required dimension",
          maxlength: ""
        },
        length: {
          required: "Please, provide the required dimension",
          maxlength: ""
        }
      }
    });

      $("#saveBtn").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      if (!$("#apiform").valid()) {
        return false 
      } else {
          
              //serialize form data
    var url = $("form").serialize();

    //function to turn url to an object
    function getUrlVars(url) {
      var hash;
      var myJson = {};
      var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
      for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split("=");
        myJson[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
      return JSON.stringify(myJson);
    }
         
    //pass serialized data to function
    var test = getUrlVars(url);

    //post with ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/api/post/create.php",
      data: test,
      ContentType: "application/json",
      success: function () {
        alert("successfully posted");
      },
      error: function () {
        
        alert("SKU already exists");
      },
    });

      };
  
  });

});
```

the form...

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h2>Product List</h2>
    
      <button class="save-btn" id="saveBtn">SAVE</button>
      
    
  </header>
    <form id="apiform">
      <div class="input-data">
        <label id="sku-label" for="sku">SKU</label>
        <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" class="form-control" placeholder="#sku" autocomplete="on" />

        <div class="input-data">
          <label id="name-label" for="name">Name </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="#name" autocomplete="on" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-data">
          <label id="price-label" for="price">Price ($)</label>
          <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="#price" autocomplete="on" />
        </div>


        <div class="input-switcher">
          <label for="productType">Type Switcher</label>
          <select id="productType" name="productType" value="productType" onchange="selectChanged()">
            <option value="" style="visibility: hidden;">Please select</option>
            <option value="dvd">DVD</option>
            <option value="book">Book</option>
            <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="dvd">
          <div class="data-input product">
            <label for="size">Size (MB):</label>
            <input type="number" id="size" name="size" class="form-control " autocomplete="on">
            <p class="describe">Please provide size in (MB)</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="book">
          <div class="data-input product">
            <label for="weight">Weight (KG):</label>
            <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" class="form-control " autocomplete="on">
            <p class="describe">Please provide weight in KG</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="furniture">
          <div class="data-input product">
            <label for="height">Height (CM):</label>
            <input type="number" id="height" name="height" class="form-control " autocomplete="on">
            <p class="describe">Please provide measurements in (CM)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="data-input product">
            <label for="length">Length (CM):</label>
            <input type="number" id="length" name="length" class="form-control" autocomplete="on">
            <p class="describe">Please provide measurements in (CM)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="data-input product">
            <label for="width">Width (CM):</label>
            <input type="number" id="width" name="width" class="form-control " autocomplete="on">
            <p class="describe">Please provide measurements in (CM)</p>
          </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Any assistance would be great, thank you...

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please read [ask]. "it is not working for me" is not a [useful description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)). You should also provide a [mcve] (your code appears to be neither complete (you are missing two libraries that you depend on) or minimal (you should be able to reduce it down to one or two fields)) using the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Comment: Yep, forgot to add the most important aspect, very sorry. I've edited the question with the error I'm getting.

Comment: That is WRONG`.on("#saveBtn").click(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you learned `.on("#saveBtn").click(` but that is wrong.

If you did `.find("#saveBtn").click(` or `$("#saveBtn").click(...)` it would work, but you are not using the validate code correctly.

You should be using the [submitHandler](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) to know when the form is valid and submitted by the user.

```
$("#apiform").validate({
  messages: { ... },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // call your ajax code here
  }
});
```

Comment: Whilst searching how to achieve the validation, I stumbled upon that 'solution', which was wrong, thanks for the advice, it certainly helps a lot. 
On the other hand, how would I incorporate the deleteBtn with the submitHandler?

Comment: I have no idea what "deleteBtn" is supposed to do. NO where in your code is a delete button.

Comment: Yes, sorry its #saveBtn, and it was not included in the code above... I've edited my mistake, my bad...

Comment: Put the button in the form.... And it will submit the form and trigger the validation.

Comment: according to the task, the button should not be in the form...

Comment: pretty dumb task, so have the button trigger the form submit. Or you use the form attribute on the button.